# проблема с циклом for в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите программу, на вход которой подаётся список чисел одной строкой. Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести сумму двух его соседей. Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними, одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце этого списка. Например, если на вход подаётся список "1 3 5 6 10", то на выход ожидается список "13 6 9 15 7" (без кавычек).

Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же.

Вывод должен содержать одну строку с числами нового списка, разделёнными пробелом. 
При значении с == 3
цикл for не выполняет команду
почему?

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
b = len(a)-1
long = len(a)
i = 0
for c in range(long+1):
 if long == 1:
        print(a[0])
 elif c == a[0] : # первый символ
        first = a[1] + a[b]
        print(first, end=' ')
        i+=1
 elif c == b : # последний символ
        last = a[-2]+a[0]
        print(last,end=' ')
        break
 elif c > 0  :
       n = (a[i-1]+a[i+1])
       print(n,end=' ')
       i +=1
```

Comment: 1. Разберись с тем, в какой переменной что содержится. Например, что содержится в b и в с?Очень помогают нормальные имена переменных, а не просто буквы, в которых ты сам через пять строк запутаешься. 2. Что означает "не выполняет команду"? Какую команду?

Answer (score 1):

Я предложу свой вариант решения:

```
string = '1 3 5 6 10'
list_vals = [int(i) for i in string.split()]
res = []
for val in range(len(list_vals)):
    if len(list_vals) == 1:
        res.append(list_vals[0])
        break
    elif val == 0:
        res.append(list_vals[-1] + list_vals[1])
    elif val == len(list_vals) - 1:
        res.append(list_vals[-2] + list_vals[0])
    else:
        res.append(list_vals[val - 1] + list_vals[val + 1])

for i in res:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Вывод:

```
13 6 9 15 7
```

Comment: Для чего continue? Убрать и добавить else, повысится читаемость.

Comment: Чтобы ниже не обрабатывалось(`res.append(list_vals[val - 1] + list_vals[val + 1])`)

Comment: А и не будет, потому что если выполняется if или elif, то следующие ветки не выполняются.

Comment: ок, точно, спасибо. По привычке хочу усложнить...

Answer (score 1):

вроде как поддерживаются отрицательные указатели. То есть последний будет [-1]

```
    string = '1 3 5 6 10'
    def q_1320361(s):
        #https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1320361/
        tmp = s.split(' ')
        l_tmp = len(tmp)
        if l_tmp == 1: return s
        ts = [int(x) for x in tmp]
        res = [ts[i-1] + ts[i - l_tmp + 1] for i in range(l_tmp)]
        res_s = ' '.join([str(x) for x in res])
        return res_s
    s = string
    print(q_1320361(s))
```

Comment: Все ок, но непонятен практический смысл строки s = string...

Comment: ну так проверял на разных вариантах...

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю еще вариант в одну строчку. Перестраиваем исходный список в два новых: первый с переносом первого элемента в конец, второй с переносом последнего элемента в начало.

Полученные два списка через `zip()` объединяем и суммируем строки:

```
inp = '1 3 5 6 10'
nums = list(map(int, inp.split()))
sums = [sum(row) for row in zip([*nums[1:], nums[0]], [nums[-1], *nums[0:-1]])] if len(nums) > 1 else nums
print(*sums, sep=' ')  # 13 6 9 15 7
```

Answer (score 0):

## И покороче

```
     def q_1320361_1(s):
         ts = [int(x) for x in s.split(' ')]
         l_tmp = len(ts)
         if l_tmp == 1: return s
         return ' '.join([str(int(ts[i - 1]) + int(ts[i - l_tmp + 1]))
                         for i in range(l_tmp)])
    s = '1 3 5 6 10'
    print(q_1320361_1(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Генератор `g` отвечает за вывод предыдущих и последующих элементов. Вот пример его работы для списка длины 10. Работа основана на поддержке отрицательных индексов при обращении к списку:

> ```
> g(-1)           ->  9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
> исходный список ->  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> g(-9)           ->  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
> ```

Чтобы получить нужные суммы сложим вывод генераторов поэлементно.

В самом начале функции `sums` проверка случая когда число только одно:

```
def sums(a):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return a

    def g(j):
        return (a[i] for i in range(j, j + len(a)))

    return map(sum, zip(g(-1), g(-len(a) + 1)))


a = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
print(*sums(a))
```

> ```
> $ echo 1 3 5 6 10 | python sums.py 
> 13 6 9 15 7
> ```